# unsuccessful attempt to change domains- wordpress re-routing to old domain

Tags: wp-admin, options, domain

I've tried to switch a website from zoparealty.com to [zoparealtygroup.com](http://zoparealtygroup.com).

When I go to zoparealtygroup.com, I can see what appears to be a strictly HTML version of the site(no CSS, no php).

zoparealtygroup.com/wp-admin takes me to [Page Not Found](http://zoparealty.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://zoparealtygroup.com/wp-admin/&reauth=1) with a URL **using the old domain**.

What could be causing the problem? What steps can I take to remedy the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The PHP is loading at the new domain, or else you would see no HTML. The issue seems to be that your WordPress Address (in Settings -> General) is not set for your new domain.

If you have access to the DB, look for the option with the name `siteurl` in wp_options. The value *should* be your new domain.

Quick and dirty solution: add this to wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://zoparealtygroup.com');
```

Comment: I kind of suspected the cause of the problem would be along these lines. My trouble now is- I can't gain access to the WP backend; when I try to login via /wp-login.php I recieve a Page Not Found error(as described above). Trying to login via FTP(tried with both old AND new domains) resulted in an 'authentication fail' error for both.

Any ideas?

Comment: FTP connection issues won't be WordPress related. You'll have to consult your hosting company on that one.